# How to save state of html form offline and allow loading

Tags: javascript, html, csv, parsing

I am looking for a non-web solution. I.e. I have a standalone html form which I want to have the option of saving the state of all fields to a .csv/.txt/json offline. Thereafter the html file can be opened again and there is the option of loading the .csv/.txt/json file.

I tried sisyphus js but that uses LocalStorage and does not allow loading of data on another browser or terminal. The real time persistent saving onto the LocalStorage is cool though.

Edit: For example, I would like to add a save button to the follow html:
[demo](https://file.io/6E9vs8)

Comment: If you want to persist data across different machines/browsers you'll need to put that data on a database or files.

Comment: @elks What did you mean by a non web solution?

Comment: I gave an example file of what I want to achieve in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you define non-web and offline.

But if you have a local web server, you can use php to open and save to files.

If you don't want a web server, you can use local storage, which you can access via javascript. no need for a framework or library. And because the data is stored on your machine it doesn't matter if the site is hosted or just opened as file in your browser.

If you want to have the data across machines you need a web server and as Phiter some sort of database. And you need a password to protect your data

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you need something directly write/read files from the client's computer?

As far as I know, this isn't supported on most browsers because of security reasons :/

Answer (score 0):

For saving files, you can pretty easily generate a data URI and direct users to it. Newer solution can be to use something like `filesaver.js`:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

For loading saved files, you can look into the Files API.

Comment: This seem to work really well when I tried the demo I found in https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/ However, how do I do this for multiple forms and allow loading of the .txt file to fill the forms.

Comment: Filesaver just takes whatever data you give it, and lets the user save it.
For loading files, I mentioned looking into the HTML Files API. It lets the user select some file from their computer, and lets you read the data in it.

As for what is in those files and how you handle the data, is completely up to you. I would use JSON. There are nice Javascript methods to generate JSON from an object, and to parse it back into an object.

Remember if this answer has been helpful, please mark it as the best answer!

Comment: I tried to integrate filesaver.js and look into what you mentioned subsequently which I didn't quite understand. Would it be possible to show an example using the demo that I have created?

https://file.io/6E9vs8